# PostgreSQL newbie - how to create objects in a database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've just finished installing PostgreSQL and pgadmin3 on Ubuntu.  Using pgadmin, I've been able to create a new user called 'test' and also a new database with 'test' as the owner.
Now I'm trying to create tables using SQL statements... but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to do that in pgAdmin.  I don't' want to create each column individually using the GUI. 
Is there any way I can run a SQL statement like:

```
create table test 
( 
  id serial primary key, 
  name varchar(64), 
  handler varchar(16), 
  desc varchar(255) 
);
```

Comment: Just a side note: there is no advantage having column lengths that are powers of two. And there is nothing special about 255. No magical "optimization" will happen in the background. A column defined as `varchar(123)` as the same performance and storage characteristics as one defined as `varchar(371)` (and if both store the e.g. 31 characters, their actual storage requirements are identical as well).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I can create an empty table using the "new table.." menu item. Then I can edit the table once created by right clicking on it and choosing "scripts".

Answer (score 0):

You should have a button, in pgAdmin3, for opening a textbox where you can enter any sql code. Or, you may just use command line client like `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use files, which can be version-controlled in git or hg.

Here's my approach:

1. Create a schema_UP.sql file with the following content:

   > begin;
   >
   > > create table test
   > >
   > > (
   > >     id      serial primary key,
   > >
   > > name    varchar,
   > >
   > > handler varchar,
   > >
   > > desc    varchar
   > >
   > > );
   > >
   > > --- Grant privileges ON 'test' table TO 'test' user
   > >
   > > GRANT select, insert, update, delete on test to test ;
   >
   > end;
2. Create a schema_DOWN.sql file with the following content:

   > begin;
   >
   > > drop table IF EXISTS test;
   >
   > end;
3. Execute either of the following as required as you evolve your initial/early stage schema.

   - $ psql -f `schema_UP.sql` -U postgres `test` **OR**
   - $ psql -f `schema_DOWN.sql` -U postgres `test`

As your database grow you may need to refactor the schema. To such end you may need to ALTER the database schema objects (tables, indexes, constraints, columns, triggers, etc). What I do is create chronologically named UP and DOWN scripts to `apply` (UP) or `revert` (DOWN) the changes.

In the case you want to constraint the `name` column size to 100 char long, you might create and execute the following scripts:

- 201304152246_UP.sql file with the following content:

  > begin;
  >
  > ALTER table test ALTER COLUMN name SET TYPE varchar(100);
  >
  > end;
- 201304152246_DOWN.sql file with the following content:

  > begin;
  >
  > ALTER table test ALTER COLUMN name SET TYPE varchar;
  >
  > end;

With these scripts ready, you can can apply the changes via $ psql -f `<scriptname>` -U postgres `<databasename>`.

Notice that to guarantee that every schema change is applied transactionally, I enclose all the instructions with a `begin;` and `end;`. This way the script is atomic and it's either `COMMITed` or `ROLLedBACK`.

Let me know if you need further assistance. =D